# java get the list of users(names) online

Tags: java, session, servlets

I would like to get the list of users online. In [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jsp-servlet-session-listener-tutorial-example-in-eclipse-tomcat/) I could see the code that is used to get the count of users online.

I think I need to have a list that gets and stores the the usernames in `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)` and then display this list.

Please suggest if this is the correct method or if there is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is How you have to keep track of the User Sessions.
to know more go to this link--HttpSession

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/